# Simplifying $ 1^5+2^5+3^5+\dots+14^5+15^5 \pmod{13} $

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

> $$ 1^5+2^5+3^5+\dots+14^5+15^5 \pmod{13} $$

I found this question on my old textbook, it seems very trivial but my answer and the answer of book are different. My solution is that:

$$ [1^5+2^5+3^5+4^5+5^5+6^5+(-6)^5+(-5)^5+(-4)^5+(-3)^5+(-2)^5+(-1)^5+0^5+1^5+2^5] \pmod{13} $$

So, it gives us $33\pmod{13}=7$, but the answer is $8$. Where am I missing?

Moreover, if you know any trick or shortcut for these types of problem, can you share your knowledge?

Comment: Wolfram says $7$ too. Your book may be wrong.

Comment: I say $7$ too, or $-6$.

Comment: The correct answer is $7$

Comment: For a shortcut, use the formula for the sum of the first $n$ fifth powers. But your approach is already short anyway (and elegant!)

Comment: If such tricks do not work, best is to use Faulhabers formula's.

Comment: @Peter, why bother with all that, when the OP's solution is the obvious way to go here?

Comment: @TonyK In this special case, yes. But the author also searches for a more general approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $5$ is prime to $\phi(13)=12$, each residue $\bmod 13$ is the fifth power of one residue and then

$1^5+2^5+...13^5\equiv1+2+...+13\equiv 78\equiv0\bmod 13$.

So the given sum reduces to $14^5+15^5\equiv1^5+2^5\equiv33\equiv7$.

And $7$ is correct.

Either the book is wrong or, as sometimes happens, you mistakenly read an answer to an adjacent problem.  That, of course, cannot be resolved here.

Comment: Why bother calculating the sum of the first thirteen positive integers when we know $\mathbf Z/13\mathbf Z$ is a group, so the sum is obvious?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy here because $Z/2Z$ is a group and $1+2\not\equiv0\bmod2$.

Comment: How do you know that getting the residues to the fifth power is a permutation?

Comment: The sum of all elements of a group depends on whether the order of the group is even or odd.

Comment: Well going Z13 is a group of order 13, so each element has order 13. So how do we know that $a^5 \neq b^5$

Comment: @everstudent because $5$ is prime to $12$ and thus $x^5\equiv r$ will always have a solution; to wit $r\equiv(r^{1+2×12}\equiv r^{25}$ forcing a solution $x\equiv(r^5)$ .  By the pegeinhole principle the solution is unique.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: I forgot to add it's a group of odd order.

Comment: @OscarLanzi thanks for this elegant clarification, but i wonder that what is the name of the rule which you wrote in the beginning such that "Since 5 is prime to ϕ(13)=12, each residue mod13 is the fifth power of one residue."

Comment: @LEO: because 5 has an inverse mod. 12, exponentiation to the fifth power has an inverse, say u, the exponentiation to the u-th power.

Comment: My bad, I was wrong to look at the additive group $Z_{13}$. Looking at the multiplicative group $Z_{12}$, which has 12 elements(which ofc can have order 1,2,3,4,6,12). I don't see why we can't have $a^5 = b^5 : a \neq b$.